# How can i sort timestamp data?

Tags: firebase, flutter, sorting, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp

deliverydate is a variable in firebase which contains the timestamp. How to sort the data by using that. I tried that like this. what mistake I did please explain me.

```
  List<DocumentSnapshot> list = [];
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> stream;

  List<OrderModel> allData = new List();

  @override
  void initState() {

    stream = Firestore.instance.collection("Users").snapshots();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


    return Scaffold(

      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: stream,
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> newListItem) {
          if (!newListItem.hasData) return SizedBox();
          if (newListItem.hasError) return Text("error");
          if (newListItem.hasData) {

            return ListView.builder(

              itemBuilder: (context, i) {

                return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: Firestore.instance
                        .collection("Users")
                        .document("${newListItem.data.documents[i].documentID}")
                        .collection("Orders")
                        .snapshots(),

                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) return SizedBox();
                      if (snapshot.hasError) return Text("error");
                      if (snapshot.hasData)
                        return Column(

                            **children: snapshot.data.documents.map((e) {

                              allData.add(new OrderModel());

                              int i = 0;

                              allData[i].Address1 = e.data["address"]["addressline1"];
                              allData[i].Address2 = e.data["address"]["addressline2"];
                              allData[i].orderid = e.data["orderid"];
                              allData[i].chef_displayname = e.data["chef_displayname"];
                              allData[i].chef_id = e.data["chef_id"];
                              allData[i].total = e.data["total"].toString();
                              allData[i].deliveryDate = e.data["deliveryDate"].toDate().toString();
                            
                            i++;**

                            if (e.data["order_status"] == 2)
                            return Container(
                              decoration:
                                  BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(width: 5.0)),
                              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 30, bottom: 0),

                              child: Column(children: <Widget>[

                                   SelectableText("Order ID: " + allData[i-1].orderid, style: TextStyle(
                                    fontSize: 20,
                                    color: Colors.purple,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold), ),

                                SizedBox(height: 10),

                                SelectableText("chef_displayname: " + allData[i-1].chef_displayname,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor), ),

                                SizedBox(height: 10),


                                SelectableText(
                                  "DeliveryDate: " +
                                      allData[i-1].deliveryDate,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 20,
                                      color: Colors.blue[900],
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),
                               
                                SizedBox(height: 10),

                                SelectableText(
                                  "Total Amount:  ₹ " + allData[i-1].total,
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 15,
                                      color: Colors.red[900],
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                ),

                                SizedBox(height: 10),

                                SelectableText("Address1: " +
                                    allData[i-1].Address1),

                                SelectableText("Address2: " +
                                    allData[i-1].Address2),


                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 30,
                                ),

                                  
                        }).toList());

                    });
              },
              itemCount: newListItem.data.documents.length,
            );
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe I am blind, but I do not see you sorting. It is always good practice to add some comment at the pace of interest in the code (and to remove not necessary code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any sorting in your code. I tend to use `compareTo` when sorting by date: https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/DateTime/compareTo.html

To sort by date you can do something like this:

```
// If the date is a DateTime instance

objectsWithDate.sort((object1, object2) {
  return object1.date.compareTo(object2.date);
});



// If the date is NOT a DateTime instance

objectsWithDate.sort((object1, object2) {
  DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse(object1.date);
  DateTime date2 = DateTime.parse(object2.date);

  return date1.compareTo(date2);
});
```